# Trigger change or input when javascript changes input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I'm working in a little project with **JQuery**, and i having a problem removing error classes from html elements.

I'm using `$('selector').on('input')` to get the event and remove the `input` class, my problem is when the field is generated with JavaScript;

**Example**

```js
  $('#one').on('input',function(){
        $('#two').val(  $('#one').val()  );
    });


    $(':input').on('input', function ()
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass('example'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('example');
        }
    });
```

```css
 .example
    {
        color: orange;
        background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Normal Case</h2>
        <input type="text" class="example">

        <h2>Problem</h2>
        <label for="one">#ONE</label>
        <input type="text" class="example" id="one">
        <br/>
        <label for="two">#TWO</label>
        <input type="text" class="example" readonly="readonly" id="two">
```

In this case, i change `#two` value when `#one` changes, `#one` remove `.example` but `#two` dont

I need to remove `.example` class from `#two` `input`

**EDIT:** I want to do it in a generic way because i have a LOT of this cases in my project

Is some way to trigger that kind of changes?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the code I wrote below help you. It's not perfect but it's a good point of start. 

I added a custom attribute that I called `data-group` for the inputs that are of the same "group".

I also modified the listener for `input` in a way that from a single listener function, you will have all inputs listening.

Check if this helps you.

```js
$('.example').on('input',function(){
    var value = this.value; 
    var groupName = $(this).attr('data-group');
    var groupElems = $("[data-group='"+groupName+"']");
    groupElems.removeClass('example');
    groupElems.val(value);
});
```

```css
.example
    {
        color: orange;
        background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Problem</h2>
<label for="one">#ONE</label>
<input type="text" class="example" data-group="group1" id="one">
<br/>
<label for="two">#TWO</label>
<input type="text" class="example" data-group="group1" readonly="readonly" id="two">

        <h2>Problem</h2>
<label for="three">#THREE</label>
<input type="text" class="example" data-group="group2" id="three">
<br/>
<label for="four">#FOUR</label>
<input type="text" class="example" data-group="group2" readonly="readonly" id="four">

        <h2>Problem</h2>
<label for="five">#FIVE</label>
<input type="text" class="example" data-group="group3" id="five">
<br/>
<label for="six">#SIX</label>
<input type="text" class="example" data-group="group3" readonly="readonly" id="six">
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `true` branch of your `if` statement, use the **[`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** method, along with a selector to find the next `input` following `this`. That way, when the first input has the class removed, the next input that follows it will have its class removed as well.

Also, change your `input` event setup so that it is set to work on `input` elements of a certain class in the first place and give the first of each set of `input`s that class.

```js
$('#one').on('input',function(){
  $('#two').val(  $('#one').val()  );
});

// Only when an input with the "input" class gets input
$('input.input').on('input', function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('input')) {
     $(this).removeClass('input');
     
     // Find the next input sibling that follows "this"
     $(this).nextAll("input").removeClass("input");
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  color: orange;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Normal Case</h2>
<input type="text" class="input">

<h2>Problem</h2>
<label for="one">#ONE</label>
<input type="text" class="input" id="one">
<br>
<label for="two">#TWO</label>
<input type="text" class="input" readonly="readonly" id="two">
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for response, the thing is, i only need `#two` to remove the class if `#one` does it, not if any input does it

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal That's what this code does because the extra line is only run if the true branch of the `if` statement is hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can check, if the current field is `#one` using [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) :

```
$(':input').on('input', function () {


       if(($(this).is("#one"))) {

            if ($('#two').hasClass('example'))
            {
                $('#two').removeClass('example');
            }

       }

       if ($(this).hasClass('example'))
       {
           $(this).removeClass('example');
        }
});
```

Comment: The OP says that this will be a repeating pattern, so the answer can't be based on `id`s because `id`s need to be unique.